# Behaviour of this function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Consider the function $f(n,a) = n^{-a}-n^{a-1}$ 
(i)I have to investigate the function for n between 1 to infinity and a between 0 to 1 . I think the function starts from zero at 1 reaches a maxima and again reduces to zero. What is its maxima for variable a and variable n? 
(ii)Also if the sum $\sum\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty g(n)f(n,a)=0$ where the first sum is over variable a .Impose condition on g(n) such that a=0.5 for all natural number n between 1 and infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You do not need to think that, for n=1, f(n,a) is 0; it is. Next, you say that the function goes through a maximum. If you start from 0, in order to reach a maximum, you need to have a positive derivative in order the function increases.

So, what is the derivative of f(n,a) with respect to n and what is its value if n=0 ? Does the value of "a" of any impact ?

By the way, what does happen if the exponents are identical (-a = a - 1) ?

I am sure you can continue from here.

Comment: @ Claude Thank you Can you answer my second question

Comment: @Surya. For the time being, I don't have any idea for the second question. If I find anything, I shall post it. Cheers.